# How can I continue adding nodes in my linked list with a while loop?

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm currently learning linked list and I have discovered the basics of coding it and I fully understand them. However, I have a certain amount of nodes preset, so the user would not be able to add more. How would one implement a while loop to keep cycling through and asking the user if they want to add another piece of data.

Here is the code that I already have so far:

```
public class List {

    public int x;
    public List ptr = null;

}
```

Above is the object class for List. List contains a data type of x and a pointer.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List front = new List();
        front.x = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a value"));

        List l1 = new List();
        l1.x = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a value"));

        List l2 = new List();
        l2.x = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a value"));

        front.ptr = l1;
        l1.ptr = l2;

        printNodes(front);

    }

    public static void printNodes(List p) {

        while (p != null) {

            System.out.print(p.x + " ");
            p = p.ptr;

        }

    }

}
```

As you can see, I have 3 Nodes created, but you cannot add anymore. I'd like to have something along the lines of:

```
boolean goAgain = true;
while (goAgain) {

    //create a new node
    String again = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Add another node?");
    if (!again.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
        goAgain = false;
    }

}
```

Thank you!

P.S - I am a sophomore in high school, please use vocabulary that I will be able to understand. I wouldn't say I'm a java noob, but I'm no expert either.

Comment: Why don't you add a function in your list class called "add", which executes the add dialogue? Then,  inside your if !again.equals("yes"), call the list.add() function?

Answer (score 0):

Well I'd clean up your `while` loop to include everything in one statement. But that's just because I'm lazy. ;)

```
while (!JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Add another node?").equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) 
{
    //make a new node
}
```

As for the code to make a new node I would suggest implementing your `List` class from the `List` interface that Java has. You can read about it [here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html) If you're just starting out in Java though it might be a little hard to understand. As a comment on your existing code here:

```
List front = new List();
front.x = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a value"));
```

You're not exactly making a new `node` per-say, you're just creating new instances of your `List` class. In this case the object is labeled 'front' My suggestion is to read up more on how a `List` is meant to function. [Here](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~skrentny/cs367-common/readings/Lists/) is a good example.

Comment: `JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Add another node?").equalsIgnoreCase("yes")` throws a NullPointerException if the user clicks 'Cancel'. (The OP's code had this problem too.)

Comment: I'm not worried about catching exceptions at the moment, I just want to grasp the concept. Also, I can't have any other imports besides JOptionPane.

Comment: If you want to get the concept of a `List` down @Jon I would really take a look at the links that I have in my answer. They'll give you a good idea on how/when to use a `List`